# My FujiFilm Finepix HS50EXP used to work fine on Ubuntu 13

Tags: camera

My FujiFilm Finepix HS50EXP used to work fine on Ubuntu 13 (after installing the Fujiplay app) but now it wont recognise the camera after I upgraded to 14.10.

Please advise how I can rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

Install Common camera drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install libsbigudrv2 libsbigudrv0 guvcview
```